# Simple products not showing in associated tab

Tags: configurable-product, ce-1.9.0.1

I'm associating my simple products to the configurable products, but in the associated tab the products aren't displayed.

- There are products displayed in the tab, but not the products I need
- When I search for a specific sku there are still no products found
- The Simple products are `enabled` and `in stock`
- I've used the attributes before in other products
- The attributes are set in the simple products

Comment: are the simple products in the same attribute set as the main configurable product?

Comment: @Marius yes, they are